# Captcha alternative for form submission

Tags: php, captcha

I'm having trouble using Captcha to prevent SPAM form submissions on my blog. For that I try to use the date as an alternative way.

Scheme: I'm using (HSI) in the use of time. So the result looks like this 050332
Well, if in jQuery, my code should be like this:

```
<script>
if ($("#sessions").val() == "050332") {
    execute($myFunction)
    }
    else {
    alert("ERROR!! The time not correct");
    }
</script>
```

But many changes that must be made if you use jQuery. How do I take the VALUE of id="sessions" use PHP? I use the following code, but it does not work.

```
<input type="hidden" name="sessions" id="sessions" value="<?php echo date('hsi', time()) ?>"/>

<?php
$mydates = date('hsi', time());
if($_POST['sessions'] == $mydates){
    execute($myFunction);
}else{
    echo 'ERROR!! The time not correct';
    }
?>
```

How do I fix it? Thanks ..

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I do not understand the purpose of your. After I check, I find the root cause of this code, namely the seconds and minutes. It was too fast, so I just use hours, months and years to lock form. So, although there are trying to do spam, they can only do it one hour lifetime. Perhaps there is another answer that is better than this. Waiting for another solution :)